# Checking split horizon status with IPv6

Tags: cisco, routing, ip, ipv6, rip

In a frame relay multipoint topology where the routers are running RIP, we know that RIP by default keeps split horizon on with IPv6 and we go into the RIP process an use no ip-split horizon to disable it.

But my question is, what command do you run to check whether split horizon is enabled on disabled on that interface with IPv6?

Much thanks!

Comment: That would certainly depend on the device make and model.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Ron. I'm practicing on GNS3. This is my router information: 3700 Software (C3725-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(15)T5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc4). With RIP, there are only a few commands I know to troubleshoot, show ip protocols, show ip int .. and maybe show ip rip database. Usually, show ip int shows me the split horizon status, but this is RIP specific. And given the lack of RIP troubleshooting commands, I was wondering how we'd check this. Please do advise, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cisco devices, it is pretty easy:

```
Router> show ipv6 rip
RIP process "process1", port 521, multicast-group FF02::9, pid 62
  Administrative distance is 120. Maximum paths is 1
  Updates every 5 seconds, expire after 15
  Holddown lasts 10 seconds, garbage collect after 30
  Split horizon is on; poison reverse is off
  Default routes are generated
  Periodic updates 223, trigger updates 1
 Interfaces:
  Ethernet0/0
 Redistribution:
  Redistributing protocol bgp 65001 route-map bgp-to-rip
```

Notice the `Split horizon is on;` in the output.

Cisco has lots of documents on this sort of thing, e.g. [Chapter: Implementing RIP for IPv6](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/configuration/15-2mt/ipv6-15-2mt-book/ip6-rip.html).

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much Ron. But I had heard that it was mentioned in a Cisco article that the SH status in RIP was inherited within the protocol and hence it can't be seen?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to say was, I had read in a Cisco article that RIP split horizon with IPv6 was inherited within the protocol and hence you couldn't see the status of it. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: I have not heard that. I don't understand the inherited part. Inherited from what?

Comment: Maybe inherited was the wrong word to use. What I meant to say is split horizon in IPv6 is integrated into the Cisco iOS RIP process.

Comment: Look at this description of the IPv6 RIP `split-horizon` command: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/command/ipv6-cr-book/ipv6-s6.html#wp2339383153

Comment: Just found that page as well. Thanks for the clarification, Ron.